# How to determine in Mercurial, if changeset, specified by revision, has already been grafted?

Tags: mercurial

How can I see, if the changeset has already been grafted between branchX and default?
I know, hg graft checks this for me, there I can't graft twice, but I want to list all changesets, which were not grafted between branchX and default.
Thanks in advance for your answers.

Comment: Any chance you can change the accepted answer? This has a better answer in newer mercurial versions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This information is stored in the so-called "extra" dictionary inside the grafted changeset. This is a simple key-value mapping that you can see with `hg log --debug`.

The information is unfortunately not exposed as a revset predicate yet, so you'll have to do it the old-fashioned way: start with

```
$ hg --debug log -b branchX
```

to get the changesets on `branchX`. Then `grep` or otherwise search for lines matching

```
extra:       source=[0-9a-f]{40}
```

You could use the [Mercurial bindings](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/CommandServer#Libraries) if you want a more high-level access. There are libraries for Java, Python, and Scala at the moment.

Comment: I added the `--debug` option to the `log` command, that was confusing.

Answer (score 7):

You can use a revset to do this if you have Mercurial 2.3 or newer:

```
$ hg log -r "destination()"
```

to get a list of all of the changesets that are the destinations for grafts.  You can also do:

```
$ hg log -r "origin()"
```

to get a list of all changesets that are graft origins.  These revsets both take another revset as arguments, so you can use the full power of composable revsets to drill down in your search.